# Paragraph folding in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Notice the line numbering in the screenshot below. The lines from 2 to 20 are "folded out". To see these lines one can click the plus sign.

[image: Paragraph folding]

I want to create a document in Word with this functionality. Is it possible? It should be possible to create nested paragraphs that are "folded out".

Because I want to distribute the document, it would be good if this worked for older versions of Word.

Comment: There is outline mode which will do this for headers

Comment: @Mark Thank you for that. That answers my question, but I tried it using Word 2010, and the look of it was so mediocre that it is not useful. Also I do not know how to send a document that requires that the reader is in outline mode. In addition, I am hoping for a way to say, which paragraphs should be "folded out" and, which ones should not.

Comment: There is a plugin that provides a macro based solution...
http://www.moreaddin.com/

Comment: You can also mark text "hidden" from the Font dialog box, but there's no visible indication that it even exists at that point.  maybe create a style that is hidden and also has some kind of image watermark or something

Comment: I would have opted to have the specific document start in Outline mode; here is how to achieve this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/make-default-view-outline-in-word-document/29a178c3-673a-4e06-939a-cca132b69636

Answer (score 7):

You can only do this in Word 2013 or later by putting a title above a paragraph. To fold in or fold out the paragraph, click on the triangle circled in red on the screenshot below.

[image]

This is unfortunately impossible in older versions of Word.